# correct synchronization of a map object created in the main thread and passed onto new threads

Tags: java, dictionary, synchronization

I'm trying to develop a program that takes requests for data which is stored in a map. The map is declared in the main method as shown below:

```
Map m = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap());
synchronized(m) {
        while (listening) {

            new BrokerLookupServerHandlerThread(serverSocket.accept(), m).start();

        }
}
```

The code for the BrokerLookupServerHandlerThread takes the input and makes it one of the object's variables. If I use it in this class, will the original map be updated as well? I understand that Java is pass by value, (I'm used to C/C++) so I just wanted to be sure if this implementation of a synchronized object makes sense.

```
    private Socket socket = null;
//private String t ="MSFT";
public Map m;

public BrokerLookupServerHandlerThread(Socket socket, Map m) {
    super("NamingServerHandlerThread");
    this.socket = socket;
    this.m = m;
    System.out.println("Created new Thread to handle client");
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: For the question of original map being updated, I'd recommend trying it out yourself and seeing what happens. No need to keep this kind of discussion on a theoretic level :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes original object will be updated. I suggest you use [ConcurrentHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) though.

> A hash table supporting full
>   concurrency of retrievals and
>   adjustable expected concurrency for
>   updates. This class obeys the same
>   functional specification as Hashtable,
>   and includes versions of methods
>   corresponding to each method of
>   Hashtable. However, even though all
>   operations are thread-safe,
>   **retrieval operations do not entail locking**, and there is not any
>   support for locking the entire table
>   in a way that prevents all access.
>   This class is fully interoperable with
>   Hashtable in programs that rely on its
>   thread safety but not on its
>   synchronization details.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Would you be able to expand on why ConcurrentHashMap is recommended in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, changes made to the map will be seen by both threads.

Java does indeed use pass by value - but the value in this case is a reference (similar to a pointer). The value of a reference-type variable in Java is *always* a reference to an object, or null. It's never the object itself.

So your code won't create a new map. There are very few operations which implicitly create a new object. I can only think of the use of string literals (where the literals are interned anyway) and autoboxing of primitive types. Other than that, you'll only get a new object via the `new` operator. (Obviously any method you call could create a new object too...)

Note that this is entirely separate to the issue of *synchronization* between threads. The business about copying objects vs copying references is orthogonal to threading. In this case it looks like you've solved the threading aspect using `Collections.synchronizedMap`; as Pangea says you may want to use `ConcurrentHashMap` instead which won't use nearly as much locking (if any). Another implementation of the `ConcurrentMap` interface is [`ConcurrentSkipListMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html). Look at the docs for both classes to decide what suits you best.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification of how pass by value in Java works!